# Based on Cell Value matches column with Yes or No

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

please see the table below. I have Columns like ColA has some value, Store has Store Names. And rest column names defined as unique cell value in Store1 column(Store1 till storeN.

```
ColA  Store     Store1   Store2   Store3   Store4   Store5 
......StoreN
1     Store3     
2     Store1    
3     Store2
```

Based on Store value in a cell for that particular row corresponding column to be filled with Yes and rest column filled as No. thats how we wanted to fill it.

Example

```
ColA  Store      Store1   Store2   Store3   Store4   Store5 ......StoreN
1      Store3         No        No      Yes      No       No    ........No
```

Note : Only Store 3 column filled as Yes and Rest column filled as No.

please help me in achieving this

thank you

Comment: Please provide a sample with inner data and desured result for that source data.

Comment: If you are trying to match Store Values in Col B with Values in Row 1 then below each match Yes should appear,, is that you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***MATCH*** function wrapped with **IF** & **IFERROR** can solve the issue:

[image]

- Enter this Formula in Cell `C71`, fill Right then Down.

  `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B71,C$70:C$70,0)),"No","Yes")`

*Adjust cell reference in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Xluser ,,, keep asking !!

Comment: @fixer1234,, the `MATCH` wrapped   with `IF` & `ISERROR` is tricky part which helps to convert `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `No` & `Yes` .

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with TRUE and FALSE, this is really simple.  If you need Yes and No, you can do it with an IF test.

[image]

The formula in the first data row, for C2:

```
=$B2=C$1
```

You copy or drag the formula across and down as needed.  The dollar signs lock the store reference to column B and the column heading reference to row 1.  It just compares the store to the column heading.  If they are the same, the result is TRUE.  If different, FALSE.

The formula for the second data row, for C3:

```
=IF($B3=C$1,"Yes","No")
```

It's the same logic, but the IF test lets you assign whatever you want to the true and false results.

You can take advantage of that to make it even easier to see the matches.  Instead of "No" for the false result, use a null (two double quotes with nothing between them: `""`).  Then everything will be blank but the matches, so they will stand out.